# Nokia Glance in Landscape mode

Tags: 8.0, lumia, glance

Is it possible to show the Nokia Glance screen in landscape mode? We are using a dock that holds the phone in landscape mode for a Lumia 925 and it is a little annoying that the clock is shown sideways.

Update: The "Black" Update by Nokia is already installed, I know the feature isn't there either.

Update 2: The feature [has been suggested here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4578288-landscape-view-glance-screen-), please upvote it if you want it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. And as someone who has a Lumia 1520 with the Nokia Black update, that feature isn't in there either.

Answer (score 2):

The latest iteration of `Nokia Glance` will be what is packaged in the Lumia Black update. The newest features are [highlighted here and there is no mention of landscape mode](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/nokia-lumia-black-glance-20).

[I'd suggest opening a ticket here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions?query=glance) if a similar ticket doesn't already exist. Representatives from the Windows Phone/Nokia teams do look at this forum and post feedback when available.

Comment: Thanks, the feature was already suggested there (albeit with only one vote). I Upvoted the existing suggestion. Looks like I have to look for alternative apps.